# How to select some columns with AWK?

Tags: linux, awk

I want to select some columns in a file and run some command on it.
so my script is this

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$19}' test.txt > outpot.txt
```

but this print it to another file and I tried to do this

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' test.txt | next commands
```

(This commands works fine! I did a mistake and I don't know how to remove this question)

is it possible to make this command shorter like instead of writing all columns just write `$1-7 && $9-15 && $19` (but this is not really important I just wondered if it's possible). The main thing is to be able to choose that columns

Comment: you say it didn't work, but in what way?   did you get an error?

Comment: ya I got a syntax error. can it be the error of my next command? but that command works perfectly with out this command at the begging!

Comment: sorry I find out that there was a mistake in my second script! I thought that the mistake was in this command( which I was wrong)

Comment: I would vote to reopen this question if I was able to.  It is the first Google result for "awk select columns."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated based on [glennjackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) suggestion:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ((1<=i && i<=7) || (9<=i && i<=15) || i==19) printf("%s ", $i); print ""}' file
```

Comment: `i` is an integer. Why do regex comparisons?

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. You are right, but I wasn't able to do multiple integer comparisons in `if`. What would you recommend?

Comment: `if ((1<=i && i<=7) || (9<=i && i<=15) || i==19) printf "%s%s" $i FS`

Answer (score 3):

To answer one part of your question, in awk script you can do:

```
{
   for (i=1; i<=7; i++)
      print $i;
   for (i=9; i<=15; i++)
      print $i;
   print $19;
}
```